# Add "latest items by category" block in item view page of K2 component

Tags: joomla, components, joomla-k2

I am using Joomla! K2 v2.4.1 component on Joomla! v1.5.23. I want to display latest items by category in the item view page, the category being the current one which the current viewed item belongs to.

There are modules which I can use to display most recent items by category but I want to modify item.php and other related files (actually I don't know which files to edit except the item.php template file) to accommodate this requirement. Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, which files do I need to edit and with what code?

Given below is what I think is used to retrieve latest items by category.

```
class K2ViewLatest extends JView {

    function display($tpl = null) {
        $mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
        $params = &JComponentHelper::getParams('com_k2');
        $user = &JFactory::getUser();
        $cache = &JFactory::getCache('com_k2_extended');
        $limit = $params->get('latestItemsLimit',3);
        $limitstart = JRequest::getInt('limitstart');
        $model = &$this->getModel('itemlist');
        $itemModel = &$this->getModel('item');

        if($params->get('source')){
            $categoryIDs = $params->get('categoryIDs');
            if(is_string($categoryIDs) && !empty($categoryIDs)){
                $categoryIDs = array();
                $categoryIDs[]=$params->get('categoryIDs');
            }
            $categories = array();
            JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'tables');
            if(is_array($categoryIDs)){
                foreach($categoryIDs as $categoryID){
                    $category = & JTable::getInstance('K2Category', 'Table');
                    $category->load($categoryID);
                    if ($category->published && ($category->access <= $user->get('aid', 0))) {

                        //Merge params
                        $cparams = new JParameter($category->params);
                        if ($cparams->get('inheritFrom')) {
                            $masterCategory = &JTable::getInstance('K2Category', 'Table');
                            $masterCategory->load($cparams->get('inheritFrom'));
                            $cparams = new JParameter($masterCategory->params);
                        }
                        $params->merge($cparams);

                        //Category image
                        if (! empty($category->image)) {
                            $category->image = JURI::root().'media/k2/categories/'.$category->image;
                        } else {
                            if ($params->get('catImageDefault')) {
                                $category->image = JURI::root().'components/com_k2/images/placeholder/category.png';
                            }
                        }

                        //Category plugins
                        $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
                        JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
                        $category->text = $category->description;
                        $dispatcher->trigger('onPrepareContent', array ( & $category, &$params, $limitstart));
                        $category->description = $category->text;

                        //Category K2 plugins
                        $category->event->K2CategoryDisplay = '';
                        JPluginHelper::importPlugin('k2');
                        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onK2CategoryDisplay', array(&$category, &$params, $limitstart));
                        $category->event->K2CategoryDisplay = trim(implode("\n", $results));
                        $category->text = $category->description;
                        $dispatcher->trigger('onK2PrepareContent', array ( & $category, &$params, $limitstart));
                        $category->description = $category->text;

                        //Category link
                        $link = urldecode(K2HelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($category->id.':'.urlencode($category->alias)));
                        $category->link = JRoute::_($link);
                        $category->feed = JRoute::_($link.'&format=feed');

                        JRequest::setVar('view', 'itemlist');
                        JRequest::setVar('task', 'category');
                        JRequest::setVar('id', $category->id);
                        JRequest::setVar('featured', 1);
                        JRequest::setVar('limit', $limit);
                        JRequest::setVar('clearFlag', true);

                        $category->name = htmlspecialchars($category->name, ENT_QUOTES);
                        $category->items = $model->getData('rdate');


                        JRequest::setVar('view', 'latest');
                        JRequest::setVar('task', '');

                        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($category->items); $i++) {

                            if ($user->guest){
                                $hits = $category->items[$i]->hits;
                                $category->items[$i]->hits = 0;
                                $category->items[$i] = $cache->call(array('K2ModelItem', 'prepareItem'), $category->items[$i], 'latest', '');
                                $category->items[$i]->hits = $hits;
                            }
                            else {
                                $category->items[$i] = $itemModel->prepareItem($category->items[$i], 'latest', '');
                            }

                            $category->items[$i] = $itemModel->execPlugins($category->items[$i], 'latest', '');

                            //Trigger comments counter event
                            $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
                            JPluginHelper::importPlugin ('k2');
                            $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onK2CommentsCounter', array ( & $category->items[$i], &$params, $limitstart));
                            $category->items[$i]->event->K2CommentsCounter = trim(implode("\n", $results));

                        }
                        $categories[]=$category;
                    }


                }
            }
            $source = 'categories';
            $this->assignRef('blocks', $categories);

        } else {
            $usersIDs = $params->get('userIDs');
            if(is_string($usersIDs) && !empty($usersIDs)){
                $usersIDs = array();
                $usersIDs[]=$params->get('userIDs');
            }

            $users = array();
            if(is_array($usersIDs)){
                foreach($usersIDs as $userID){

                    $userObject = JFactory::getUser($userID);
                    if (!$userObject->block) {

                        //User profile
                        $userObject->profile = $model->getUserProfile($userID);

                        //User image
                        $userObject->avatar = K2HelperUtilities::getAvatar($userObject->id, $userObject->email, $params->get('userImageWidth'));

                        //User K2 plugins
                        $userObject->event->K2UserDisplay = '';
                        if (is_object($userObject->profile) && $userObject->profile->id > 0) {

                            $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
                            JPluginHelper::importPlugin('k2');
                            $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onK2UserDisplay', array(&$userObject->profile, &$params, $limitstart));
                            $userObject->event->K2UserDisplay = trim(implode("\n", $results));

                        }
                        $link = K2HelperRoute::getUserRoute($userObject->id);
                        $userObject->link = JRoute::_($link);
                        $userObject->feed = JRoute::_($link.'&format=feed');
                        $userObject->name = htmlspecialchars($userObject->name, ENT_QUOTES);
                        $userObject->items = $model->getAuthorLatest(0,$limit,$userID);

                        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($userObject->items); $i++) {

                            if ($user->guest){
                                $hits = $userObject->items[$i]->hits;
                                $userObject->items[$i]->hits = 0;
                                $userObject->items[$i] = $cache->call(array('K2ModelItem', 'prepareItem'), $userObject->items[$i], 'latest', '');
                                $userObject->items[$i]->hits = $hits;
                            }
                            else {
                                $userObject->items[$i] = $itemModel->prepareItem($userObject->items[$i], 'latest', '');
                            }

                            //Plugins
                            $userObject->items[$i] = $itemModel->execPlugins($userObject->items[$i], 'latest', '');


                            //Trigger comments counter event
                            $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
                            JPluginHelper::importPlugin ('k2');
                            $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onK2CommentsCounter', array ( & $userObject->items[$i], &$params, $limitstart));
                            $userObject->items[$i]->event->K2CommentsCounter = trim(implode("\n", $results));


                        }

                        $users[]=$userObject;
                    }

                }
            }
            $source = 'users';
            $this->assignRef('blocks', $users);
        }

        //Look for template files in component folders
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'templates');
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'templates'.DS.'default');

        //Look for overrides in template folder (K2 template structure)
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$mainframe->getTemplate().DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates');
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$mainframe->getTemplate().DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates'.DS.'default');

        //Look for overrides in template folder (Joomla! template structure)
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$mainframe->getTemplate().DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'default');
        $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$mainframe->getTemplate().DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2');

        //Assign params
        $this->assignRef('params', $params);
        $this->assignRef('source', $source);

        //Set layout
        $this->setLayout('latest');

        //Display
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

}
```

But this file is somehow used to retrieve items in using menu link. I am sorry if this is not the case.

Comment: anyone plz. I am stuck at this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work the way you want you would have to modify the K2 item model. The data you want to display (recent items in category) is not currently being pulled from the database so you'd have to change to model to accommodate that. You would be much better off using the K2 content module to pull the most recent items instead. It wouldn't require hacking any core K2 code.

Also, you really need to update your software. K2 is on v2.5.4 and Joomla is on 2.5.1.